# Android tabLayout last selected tab color is not updating correctly

Tags: android, colors, tabs, android-tablayout

I have a tablayout with 4 tabs. When I select a tab, the text and icon of that tab should be red, and the other tabs should be grey.

To update the icon I have created two different versions, and updating it in my overridden OnTabSelectedListener, but when I add this to the tablayout the text colour seems to "lag behind". The last selected tab text is still red and not updated until I press on another new tab.

When I remove the OnTabSelectedListener, the colours work properly, but then I cant update the icon... Im not able to update the text colour directly on the tabLayout.tab item either.

Is this a bug in Android or am I missing something?

---

**activity_tab.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.oivind.tabsexample.TabActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        style="@style/NASTabLayout">

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**tabActivity.java onCreate:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    viewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_icon_error);
    for(int i = 1; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_icon_error_grey);
    }

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            tab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_icon_error);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            tab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_icon_error_grey);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            tab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_icon_error_grey);
        }
    });
}
```

[image: screenshot of the bug]

Comment: This only happens when I set it back to the grey icon in "OnTabUnselected". Really seems like a bug in Android.

Comment: Me too i'm facing this problem. May be the way to solve this is by using a custom view for the tab item

Comment: @Senator Thats exactly what I ended up doing. Created my own custom tab component which I could set color and icon on directly. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had also this error and i solved it by adding `tabLayout.setScrollPosition(tab.getPosition(),0f,true);` to the end of ***onTabSelected*** as follows:

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                tab.setIcon(navActiveIcons[tab.getPosition()]);
                tabLayout.setScrollPosition(tab.getPosition(),0f,true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                tab.setIcon(navIcons[tab.getPosition()]);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

**THIS IS A QUICK FIX AND DOES NOT SOLVE THE ORIGINAL PROBLEM**

Fixed it by looping through the tabs and set the grey icon on every click:

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                for(int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_icon_error_grey);
                }
                tab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_icon_error);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

If someone knows how to do this properly, please tell. :)

Comment: I dont know why this is down-voted. It clearly marks that this is not the correct solution, but it fixes the problem.

Comment: your solution doesn't fix the problem. With your solution, the text color will still remain with the active color. It work well for the icons but not for the text color

Comment: Long time since I saw this. I did it in a slight different way in the project, but basicvally the same: Loop through and set icon and text color on the custom defined tab component.